# Percent encoded characters in URL gives error in browser

Tags: .net, html, url-encoding, idn

I'm having problem with URL's that include special characters. The rendered HTML if I use `NavigateUrl='Eval("website")'` is this:

```
<a href="http://www.v%c3%a4rnamo.nu">www.värnamo.nu</a>
```

If I try to encode it like this `NavigateUrl='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("website")) %>'` I get this output, which doesn't work either.

```
<a href="http://www.v&/"288;rnamo.nu">www.värnamo.nu</a>
```

I tried setting charset in the meta tag to `UTF-8` and `iso-8859-1`, but it didn't help, and I don't think it has to do with that either.

Try clicking this link: http://www.v%c3%a4rnamo.nu and you'll get the same response.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: What's the problem with the first one?

Comment: If I click any of the links I get "Server not found". Can not find the server at *www.v%c3%a4rnamo.nu* or *www.v&/"288;rnamo.nu*. The text in the browser looks good though and if I press enter in the url field I can browse to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this to work now. I used the code at this [LINK](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/06/punycode-in-vbnet-for-idn-domains.html)

In my aspx page I use this in the NavigateUrl property:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# idnMapping(Convert.ToString(Eval("website"))) %>'
```

Which calls the function:

```
public static string idnMapping(string text) {
    System.Globalization.IdnMapping idn = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping();
    return idn.GetAscii(text);
}
```

Now when I view the html I see

```
<a href="http://xn--vrnamo-bua.nu">www.värnamo.nu</a>
```

And clicking this link will open the page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try punycode, which gives http://www.xn--vrnamo-bua.nu. I made this using http://www.charset.org/punycode.php, which claims to offer PHP code to do this conversion, if that helps.

Comment: Exactly how do I use this? Do you want me to combine PHP with .NET?

Comment: No...but the page I mentioned links to a page with a download link pointing at a zip file containing a PHP class that could be converted into .NET. Mainly I was suggesting a format that could encode special characters. I don't know of anything built into .NET that does this conversion, so obtaining an algorithm or code from another source seems warranted.

Comment: There's IdnMapping in .NET that uses punycode: http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/06/punycode-in-vbnet-for-idn-domains.html. Didn't work though as the browser couldn't recoginze what was converted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("website"))` instead of `HtmlEncode`

Comment: If you are running on .NET 4.0, you can try WebUtility.HtmlDecode